# YouTube video play with exoplayer library in Application

Tags: android, youtube, exoplayer

I have used the exoplayer library to play video in my application. But I can not play youtube video link using exoplayer.

I am getting below exception:

> **ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error. com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException:
>   None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor,
>   FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor,
>   Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor,
>   WavExtractor) could read the stream.**

I have searched on that but I have got the suggestion to use youtube android player API. But if we don't want to use youtube API. 
If anyone knows other option to play youtube video using exolayer only then please answer here.

Comment: try to youtube video play in webview that simple

Comment: @RickyPatel then what the use of using exoplayer.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to obtain direct links to YouTube videos for playback by ExoPlayer.

- YouTube's Android Player API is the officially supported way of playing YouTube videos in Android applications.
- Unfortunate to hear the need to use different player to stream youtube videos. This is irony since youtube app is internally using ExoPlayer.
- Hope **Google/Youtube avoids such duplicated efforts**. A YoutubeMediaSource will save the developers having to familiarize yet another media player API.

Answer (score 0):

maybe usefull for someone seeing this post. you can using this library to show youtube videos nativly in your app:

https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player