# playing video from url channel in android

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I want to play live tv channel in android app how we use live tv channel i use exoplayer but dosent work. Here is my code

```
try {
        String videoURL = "https://www.samaa.tv/live/";

        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);
        Uri videouri = Uri.parse(videoURL);
        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videouri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error : " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: `https://www.samaa.tv/live/` - This is not a video url , it's a webpage url.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCJekW1Vj5fCVEGdye_mBN6Q - I use this also but not playing

Comment: What's the error it's giving?. Also you can't play youtube url directly in exoplayer.

Comment: E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:924)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:846)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068497/youtube-video-play-with-exoplayer-library-in-application - check this answer

Comment: I use this also but it work only on uploaded video not live streaming

Comment: Then please share the code of what you have tried using youtube video view/player. Anyone looking at your current code will probably have same thought as me.

Answer (score 0):

use official youtube api instead of exo player or other library.

add Webview to your app and use this GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos
to extract the videos
or attach direct link to that api

heres the forum to youtube api and documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Answer (score 0):

Try these links below in exoplayer

- `https://youtu.be/IH0Bmc2jRio`
- `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IH0Bmc2jRio`